# Sql query to get join of two tables and both table has where query

Tags: sql, join, left-join

Stuck at join, tried left, right, left outer , right outer joins

table 1

```
selectionID    name     type
1              abc       1
2              def       1
3              ghi       2
4              dhi       2
5              gki       2
6              ppp       2
```

Table 2

```
TID    UserID    selectionID   isOK
1       10       3              0
2       19       3              0
3       10       8              0
6       10       5              1
```

Desired result is
join of
select from table 1 where type =2
select from table 2 where UserID = 10

```
selectionID    name     type    TID             userID 

3              ghi       2       1              10
4              dhi       2       undefined      undefined/null
5              gki       2       undefined      undefined/null
6              ppp       2       6              10
```

so basically i want all data from table 1 that fits in where clause and their respective data in table 2 with another where clause

As long as i have done research i need to use inner query of second table...am I going right way?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Don't tag incompatible databases.

Comment: just need query, any way its fine

Comment: Could you provide, at least, the two queries you would like joined? The solution is fairly simple, but would be easier to show if you provided the actual queries you are working with or a query that you have attempted.

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. Tables don't have a "where query"...whatever that means.

Comment: @Luckyy while you are somewhat correct in that it doesn't necessarily matter which DBMS you are using, you should either tag this as the one you are using, or specify just `sql` without a DBMS. Tagging with multiple DBMS's does not help your question at all.

Comment: select isOk, name from table 1 1 left  1 table 2 2 on 1.TID = 2.TID where  type=2 and UserId = 10

Comment: Please add your queries to your question, not here in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT t1.selectionID, t1.name, t1.type, t2.tid, t2.userID
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.type = t2.TID AND t2.userID = 10
WHERE t1.type = 2;
```

Comment: Thank you Darshan, I was failing at where clause only...thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

*Stuck at join, tried left, right, left outer , right outer joins* ... well `LEFT JOIN` is same as `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. BTW, you are looking for a `LEFT JOIN` probably like

```
select t1.selectionID,
    t1.name,
 t1.type,
 t2.TID,
 t2.UserId
from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t1.selectionID = t2.selectionID
and t2.UserId = 10
where t1.type = 2;
```

Comment: Exactly...Thanks buddy

Comment: @Luckyy if this answer and/or Darshan's answer helped you, please up-vote them and select one of them as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You were probably failing because placing the conditions in the `where` clause. If a row doesn't join you will have `null`s in its columns, so a `where` condition will discard those rows

```
select  *
from    table1 t1
left join
        table2 t2
on      t1.selectionID = t2.selectionID and
        t2.userID = 10
where   t1.type = 2
```

Another way, is to force nulled rows to be accepted, using `coalesce`

```
select  *
from    table1 t1
left join
        table2 t2
on      t1.selectionID = t2.selectionID and
where   t1.type = 2 and
        coalesce(t2.userID, 10) = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 ON t1.SelectionID = t2.SelectionID
where t1.type = 2 AND t2.UserID = 10
```

Comment: You might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and provide some explanation for the code you posted.